# How to display git ignored files with shell?

Tags: git, shell, terminal

I'm stuck in shell exercices. I have to do an exercise where I have to write a command that displays all files ignored by git.

I used this: `git status --ignored --porcelain`
It works well but it does not display as I want. Already it also displays the uncommitted files(with a serie of ??? before), and it also displays a series of "!!!" for files ignored before the word, and I would like to just display their names.

How can I do it? Is there another way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+ignored+files

Comment: `git ls-files --exclude-standard -i -o`, `git check-ignore $(find . -type f)`, `git check-ignore **/*` (requires `shopt -s globstar`).